# How do I disable a local function before it's called inside that scope function?

Tags: javascript

I have `a()` and a `b()` inside that `a()`. I can't make any change to `b()` but I want to make it unable to call from outside.

So I came up with an idea to save the reference of `b()` and then set it to `null`. However, it doesn't work.

Any tips for me?

```js
function a(){
  setTimeout(b, 1000);
  function b(){
    console.log('called');
    alert('b called');
  }
  window.bref = b;
  console.log('finish setting');
}

a();
window.bref = null;
console.log('make b() fail to call')
```

Comment: There is no way to mutate a function such that it can't be called later, in most cases. Sounds like an X/Y problem.

Comment: `b` anyway can't be called from outside directly. Do you mean you want to call `b` only once, even if `a` is called multiple times?

Comment: I want to use a button to control whether `b()` is able to be called. Without changing the content inside `b()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach: Enclose the function(s) in a self-executing anonymous function. This is useful so you can cache a flag that determines whether or not `b()` should run. Then add a static method to `a()` to  toggle this internal flag. The example below `runB` is such flag. Note that no error is thrown but you can trigger an error if you need to.

```js
(function(parent){
  var runB = true;
  
  function b(){    
    console.log('Executed b()');    
  }
  
  function a(){
    setTimeout(function(){
      if(runB) {
        b();
      } else {
        console.log('Skipped b()')
      }
    }, 500);
    console.log('Executed a()');
  }
  
  a.disableB = function(){
    runB = false;
  }
  
  parent.a = a;  
})(window);

// Run it normally
a();

// Run it without b()
setTimeout(function(){
  a();
  a.disableB();
}, 550);
```

Comment: This doesn't work. `Executed b()` still shows up in the console log.

Comment: @davidhu2000 The `Executed b()` that shows in the console is for the first  `a()` call. For the second call, `b()` is skipped.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is good practice, but you can wrap `window.bref` in another function. So here I'm checking if `window.bref` is a function, if so, call it, or do nothing. The output of this no longer calls `b()`.

```js
function a(){
  setTimeout(() => {
    typeof window.bref === 'function' ? window.bref() : null;
  }, 1000);
  function b(){
    console.log('called');
  }
  window.bref = b;
  
  console.log('finish setting');
}

a();
window.bref = null;
console.log('make b() fail to call')
```

Answer (score 0):

try using let:

```js
function a(){
  let b = function(){
    console.log('called');
    alert('b called');
  }
  setTimeout(b, 1000);
  console.log('finish setting');
}

a();
try{b();}
catch(e){console.log("b is not called")}
```